# Targeting a "for" attribute within a label tag for styling

Tags: html, css

I have a form that was generated by a WP plugin (HTML is unchangeable).  I need to hide one single field's label, and the only unique identifier it has if the `for` attribute

```
<label for="username" class="text"> Username </label>
```

I want to be able to do this:

```
~username { //Need this identifier
    display: none;
}
```

How can I access the label by this attribute and apply CSS to it?

Comment: @Quentin The accepted answer/"duplicate question"'s answer required an !important tag to work, so it didn't work as perfectly as a duplicate question solution should.

Comment: If it needed to be `!important` then that is because of other rules that were not included in the question… and has nothing to do with actually targeting the element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Attribute selector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)

```css
label[for="username"] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<label for="username" class="text"> Username </label>
```

Comment: Note that you don't have to use `label`: `[for=username] {display: none;}`